# Can a smart contract be whitelisted on a multisig wallet?

Tags: gnosis-safe

A team and I are creating an automated trading strategy, and want to use a mutlisig wallet for security. However, if every transaction needs to be approved by the members, it wouldn't be automated. So I am wondering if there is a way to whitelist a smart contract so when the wallet is transacting with a specific protocol it wouldn't need approval every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be done via modules: https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/contracts/modules-1

You can also take a quick look at https://gist.github.com/rmeissner/c66371a4b030109cde1020f427122462

Answer (score 0):

I also have different old multisig contracts from like 2015. Some are worth quite much now, i was able to transfer 6 million into a gnosis vault trough a proxy from a contract but dont really know how. I have a long list of old contracts.. any tips would be appriciated :) // old eth investor and crowdfunder and ICO buyer, miner and staker and so on.